Error with .NET upgrade-assistant tool "Analyze" command
I am using .NET upgrade-assistant tool with the following command: upgrade-assistant.exe analyze C:\UploadedFiles\AMSWebapi\AssetManagementStoreApp.csproj --targetFramework net8.0 -r analysis-report --serializer html --privacyMode Unrestricted --non-interactive and getting the following error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.StringExtensions.EnsureTrailingChar(String s, Char ch) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Extensions\StringExtensions.cs:line 244
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.StringExtensions.EnsureTrailingBackslash(String s) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Extensions\StringExtensions.cs:line
236
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Helpers.LocalPathHelper.PreprocessLocalPaths(String path, String rootPath, Boolean isProtected, IEnvironmentService
environment) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Helpers\LocalPathHelper.cs:line 36
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Analysis.ProjectAnalysis.GetEntryRelativePath(AnalysisEntry entry) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Analysis\ProjectAnalysis.cs:line 166
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Analysis.AnalysisBase.GetReport() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Analysis\AnalysisBase.cs:line 166
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Cli.Flow.Steps.Analysis.RunAnalysisFlowStep.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(StatusContext statusContext)
in D:\a_work\1\s\src\cli\Flow\Steps\Analysis\RunAnalysisFlowStep.cs:line 154
at Spectre.Console.Status.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Status/Status.cs:line 79
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Spectre.Console.Status.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Status/Status.cs:line 120
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Spectre.Console.Progress.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Progress/Progress.cs:line 133
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Spectre.Console.Internal.DefaultExclusivityMode.RunAsync[T](Func`1 func) in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Internal/DefaultExclusivityMode.cs:line 40
at Spectre.Console.Progress.StartAsync[T](Func`2 action) in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Progress/Progress.cs:line 116
at Spectre.Console.Status.StartAsync[T](String status, Func`2 func) in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Status/Status.cs:line 117
at Spectre.Console.Status.StartAsync(String status, Func`2 action) in /_/src/Spectre.Console/Live/Status/Status.cs:line 77
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Cli.Flow.Steps.Analysis.RunAnalysisFlowStep.GetReportAsync(IAnalysis analysis, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
in D:\a_work\1\s\src\cli\Flow\Steps\Analysis\RunAnalysisFlowStep.cs:line 150
at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Cli.Flow.Steps.Analysis.RunAnalysisFlowStep.RunAsync(IFlowContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\cli\Flow\Steps\Analysis\RunAnalysisFlowStep.cs:line 85
at Spectre.Console.Flow.FlowRunner.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\spectre.flow\Flow\FlowRunner.cs:line 98
Can someone help identify the rootcause of the error?
Want someone to provide guidance on the root cause of the above error
